# How to take an ipa file using xcode6(ios8)?

Tags: ios8, xcode6, archive, provisioning-profile, ipa

I cannot build to make ipa file in xcode6(ios8). When I archiving the build the following error will come.
[image]

I had done the search for the solution a lot. But i didn't get any solution for this problem.How can I build an ipa file using developer provisioning profile and distribution profile? Is the xcode6 version only support the adhoc distribution profile for make the build of an .ipa file in the system;not submitting to the app store?